# can't import cv2 in VS Code

Tags: python, opencv

i am trying to install and import cv2 with many ways but i can't
i am using python 3.12.1
and all the posts in stack overflow to fix it but i can't fix

i try:

```
python -m pip install cv2
```

and:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

```
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Music\file\nhandienkhuonmat.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

Comment: probably an issue of multiple pythons or different virtual environments

Answer (score 1):

I just tried running these on my machine:

```
pip3 install opencv-python
python3 (to open python interactive terminal)
import cv2
```

and everything works on my end.

So a few things could be the issue for you.

1. Did you open a new terminal after running pip install?  If not, please do so.
2. What version of python do you have installed? if it is python3, then try using 'pip3' instead of 'pip' and see it that makes a difference.

Comment: since OP's question indicates this is windows, there is probably no default python **2** anywhere. -- reopening a terminal seems pointless. environment variables don't need updating just because a python package was installed.